# ES2015: Named import translation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm following ES2015. I want to translate regular javascript import statements to ES2015 import statement(s).

> What I have:

I have javascript import line as below:

```
var db = require('../config').get('db')
```

> What I've tried:

```
import { config } from '../config'
const db = config.db
```

> NOTE

`config` folder has the `index.js` which I want to load. In the regular `var ... = require('...')` statement automatically loads `index.js` if exists. And I want the ES2015 script also automatically loads when imported.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @JordanHendrix I already tried that link. And what I tried is in "What I've tried". It seems not working.

Comment: Are you looking for `import {get} from '../config'; const db = get('db');`? You've got a function call in your first example and none in your second and it's not clear what you're expecting that to translate to.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
import { db } from '../config'
```

Assuming `db` is properly `export`-ed from config.js, that should work.

Just to clarify, there's three main kinds of imports in JS native modules:

1. Import the whole module:

   ```
   import * as foo from 'path/to/foo';
   const something = foo.something;
   ```
2. Import specific named exports of the module. This works if the module exports the appropriate objects using `export` statements:

   ```
   import { something } from 'path/to/foo';
   ```
3. Import the default export of the module. This only works if the module has an `export default` statement in it:

   ```
   import thedefaultexport from 'path/to/foo';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `'../config'` module exports a single object with a `get()` method. If this is the case, import the whole module, like so:

```
import * as config from '../config';
```

And get the database like so:

```
const db = config.get('db');
```

If possible, you might want to refactor your `'../config'` module so that it exports `db` directly.

```
export {db};
```

And then you can use the syntax @AsadSaeeduddin suggested:

```
import {dp} from '../config';
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the way to do it if the asker's modules are set up in the way described.

Comment: This is actually correct. Given the OP's code snippet, if you're calling a `get` function off the module, you either need to do `import { get } from '...'`, or do what's described in the answer.

Comment: Yes, and `import { get }` might not even work if the `get()` method references `this`.

Comment: If `get` is a top level export there is no `this` to reference (unless the user unintentionally referred to the global object as `this`, which would work regardless)

Comment: That's right, in ES2015, there would be no `this`. I guess I was thinking `'../config'` might be a Node module that uses `module.exports` to export a single object, which is pretty common these days.